# Null pointer exception at line 14

Tags: java, object

I am getting null pointer exception at line 9 of my code I am fairly new to java can someone tell me the concept and mistakes I am doing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Certificate certificate1= new Certificate(60,"cnexirk","cbnifms",77);
    Certificate certificate2= new Certificate(45,"gphspvq","pqjbhmz",62);
    Certificate certificate3= new Certificate(41,"nfpxsmp","vimiopu",89);
    Certificate certificate4= new Certificate(95,"ionouca","bsbknpx",38);
    Certificate certificate5= new Certificate(39,"yhzrafu","itnbskb",44);
    Certificate[] objArray={certificate1,certificate2,certificate3,certificate4,certificate5};
    Certificate[] objResultArray1=getEven(objArray);
    for(Certificate certificate:objResultArray1){
        System.out.println(certificate.getId()+" " + certificate.getTitle()+" " + certificate.getDate()+" " + certificate.getRank()+" ");
    }


public static Certificate[] getEven(Certificate[] cer)
{
    Certificate[] objresult=new Certificate[cer.length];
    for(int i=0;i<cer.length;i++)
    {
        if(cer[i].getRank()==77)
        {
            objresult[i]=cer[i];
        }
    }
return  objresult;
}
```

}
`

Comment: What is line 14? Ehh, line 9? Whichever line it is?

Comment: the for loop in main method

Comment: Since you only copy references to certificate where rank is 77, all the other array positions will have null reference values, so why are you confused that if fails when you try `certificate.getId()` when `certificate` is one of those null values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
if (cer[i].getRank() == 77) {
   objresult[i]=cer[i];
}
```

What if the `rank` isn't exactly `77`? The array element remains `null`.
Then, when looping the returned array `objResultArray1`

```
certificate.getId()
```

throws the `NullPointerException`.

Your `objResultArray1` array will look like

```
[Certificate@132u323, null, null, null, null]
```